# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable) ==>promptengine-compressed.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, http-status-code-406

I am working on Application where we can host Crystal reports and run them from the application. The problem I am having is that when I am trying to run any report is showing blank white screen. but it has crystal reports UI.Print export etc.. but not ruining the report showing this error Like this[image]

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable) 
aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/promptengine-compressed.js**

But when I click on the console error it open URL it opens in a new tab after that if I open report again it's work.but client will not gonna do that so i want to fix this issue.

in the whole application, there are two places where we are using this promptengine-compressed.js

one is crv.js

```
 bobj.crv.config = {
        isDebug : false, 
        scriptUri: null,  // The uri for the viewer script dir (that holds crv.js)
        skin: "skin_standard",
        needFallback: true, 
        lang: "en",
        useCompressedScripts: true,
        useAsync : true,
        indicatorOnly: false,
        resources : { 
            'HTMLPromptingSDK': { isLoaded: false, path: '../Scripts/promptengine-compressed.js' },
          'ParameterControllerAndDeps' : {isLoaded: false, path: '../../parameterUIController-compressed.js'}  
        },
        logging: { enabled: false, id: 0}
    };
```

other we are referencing on Layout Page

```
   <script src="@Url.Content("../Scripts/promptengine-compressed.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue:

The browser is expecting the MIME type for ‘crystalreportviewers/promptengine-compressed.js’ file as 
‘application/x-javascript, text/javascript’.

But in IIS, at Default Web Site/Application (Application) level the MIME type for .js file is application/javascript. 
Once I made the change I was able to see reports.

Thanks!

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28682818/406-Client-browser-IE10-does-not-accept-the-MIME-type-of-the-requested-page.html

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24977691/MIME-Type-for-Crystal-Reports-IIS-7.html

Comment: How did you do that? I can't see the answers on this links.